# How to enable nunit to log detailed test execution messages with time stamps?

Tags: logging, nunit, timestamp, log4net

We have a requirement to compare the execution time stamp of each nunit test with our product's log file. I played with adding a log4net configuration settings section to the nunit-console.exe.xml file, but it didn't seem to use it for logging. I googled and read in nunit release notes that nunit stopped using log4net for internal logging.
My question now is: Is there a way to enable detailed nunit test execution logging with time stamps?

Answer (score 0):

1. [Latest Stable release - 2.5.10](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=configFiles&r=2.5.10)
2. [Under development version - 2.6](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=configFiles&r=2.6)

For both documantation saying:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="NUnit">
      <section name="TestRunner"
        type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler"/>
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <NUnit>
    <TestRunner>
      <add key="ApartmentState" value="MTA" />
      <add key="ThreadPriority" value="Normal" />
      <add key="DefaultLogThreshold" value="Error" />
    </TestRunner>
  </NUnit>

  ...

</configuration>
```

**DefaultLogThreshold**

> Sets the level for logging captured by NUnit. In the current version
>   only log4net logging is captured, so the level must be one that is
>   defined by log4net.

So I believe log4net logging should work fine.